# Timestamp of actual image

Tags: image, timestamp

I use this code to display newest image sended from my ip cam:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
refreshImage = function(){
    img = document.getElementById("K1");
    img.src="kamera-1.php?rand=" + Math.random();
}
window.onload=window.setInterval(refreshImage, 1*1000);
</script>

<style>
.rotate180 {
-webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
-o-transform: rotate(180deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
transform: rotate(180deg);
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="rotate180">
   <img id="K1" src="kamera-1.php" alt="kamera-1" />
</div>
</body>
```

kamera-1.php is:

```
<?php 
if ($handle=opendir('./kamera-1/')) { 
while ($file = readdir($handle)) 
{ 
  $polozky[count($polozky)] = $file; 
} 
closedir($handle); 
sort($polozky); 
$i = sizeof($polozky); 
$link= 'kamera-1/'.$polozky[$i-2]; 
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently"); 
header("Location: ".$link); 
exit(); 
} 
reset($polozky); 
?>
```

IP cam is sending periodicaly new image with new name (xxxxxx_x_timestamp_yyyyy, x=MAC+user defined name, y=consecutive number). My question is: how to get just timestamp to show under actual image on my website?

Thank you in advance for your help.